# Indentation and Syntax Errors in File Organizing Script in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, syntax-error, indentation

I've been working on a file organizing script from a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRuq3SRXses&t=22s

However, I'm new to python, so much of its nuance is hidden to me.

[image]

I have two indentation errors, as well as two syntax errors, however after looking at several questions on here, I still can't seem to fix it.
I'm confident I did not mix spaces and tabs, and the person from the tutorial I used seem to use his version of the script perfectly fine.

As for the syntax errors, I do not know what the issue could be.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
import os
import shutil

origin_dir = r'D:\TTITF\Game Files and Animations\Animations\Bridges\Walk ~ Alvie - V_2 R RAW'
target_dir = r'D:\TTITF\Game Files and Animations\Animations\Bridges\Walk ~ Alvie - V_2 R TRIMMED'



for f in os.listdir(origin_dir):
    filename, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    try:
        if not file_ext:
            pass

        elif int(filename) in range(0, 60):
            shutil.move(
                os.path.join(origin_dir, f'{filename}{file_ext}')
                os.path.join(target_dir, 'V_O to V_4', f'{filename}{file_ext}'))


    except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError):
        pass
```

Comment: There's a comma missing after the first argument to `shutil.move`, but that's unrelated to the other error messages that are visible in the left half of your screenshot.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting? where does it say indentation error?

Comment: It seems you didn't learn yet how to run a Python file as a script. You seem to be pasting the contents of the file into an interactive Python session which is not how this works.

Comment: Oh, I'll look into that then. I saw the person on the tutorial use Sublime Text and thought I could just copy paste that into a python application, the correct one I had thought to use was the one just labeled "Python"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the python code on IDE such as VS code,Jupyter notebook, Pycharm ( which is mentioned in tutorial that you are watching). Most developer write code in

When you are typing in the terminal you need to type keep and give space keeping in mind the indentation needed for the code

Useful commands to write in terminal

Press enter -> To enter a new line
Double press enter -> To execute the code

Comment: It's absolutely not necessary to use an IDE in order to write and run Python code. You can use Notepad and the Windows Command Prompt just fine.

Comment: Agree, I am suggesting him based on the images presented in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded Pycharm and now I understand I was doing things very wrong.

Comment: I am glad, I could help thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In the image on the left, you're typing your code into an interactive shell, which has some limitations.  In particular, if you're entering a multiline construct such as a `try/except` block or an `if/else` block, you can't use any blank lines, otherwise the interpreter thinks the block is finished.

In the image on the right, you're typing your code at a command prompt, which is just wrong.